# trabajar con 2 o mas pc

Tags: git, github

quiero practicar el uso de git y github mientras realizo un curso, por lo que en mi trabajo quiero usar la laptop y cuando estoy en casa trabajar con la pc, quiero simular y practicar el push y pull. entonces mi pregunta es. cuando realice el push desde mi laptop hacia github, para bajar esos cambios desde y hacia mi pc, ¿debo tener otra cuenta de github y hacer un pullreques hacia mi otra cuenta? se que puedo clonar el repositorio , pero lo que quiero es simular que una persona trabaja desde la pc y otra de una laptop quiero subir y bajar cambios ralisados. muchas gracias de ante mano.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes hacerlo sin problema con una sola cuenta si quieres distinguir el portátil del ordenador lo puedes hacer con el git config. lo que recomiendo es que añadas las claves ssh públicas de los dispositivos en tu cuentas.

Comment: hola zabbix, tengo 2 ssh una la cree desde la pc y la otra la cree desde la laptop, pero realice el pull desde la pc y me arroja un error

Comment: lo que realice ahora es un clone, pero no quiero hacer clone quiero hacer pull

Comment: ¿ Que error te da ? Has cofigurado el git (git config --global user.name "FIRST_NAME LAST_NAME" y git config --global user.email "MY_NAME@example.com")